# Accessing User-created Parameters

Tags: spinnaker

This question is regarding Spinnaker. Within each Pipeline, you have the ability to define custom parameters. When a Pipeline is triggered, you have the ability to use the default value, or supply a new value to those parameters.

I assume I can create Stages within that Pipeline that will use the value of the parameters, when the Pipeline is triggered. However, I can't figure out how to access these values in any Stage of the Pipeline.

For example, I have a Pipeline "Test". I create a parameter "Version", in the configuration for "Test".

[Creating a parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66a2E.png)

Then, I add a Pipeline Stage to execute a Jenkins job. The job I have selected has a parameter, "Version".

[Using a parameter's value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3tS8.png)

When the Pipeline "Test" is triggered, I want it to use the value of the Pipeline parameter "Version" and supply it to the Jenkins job. I tried the following syntax for the Jenkins job's Version field: $Version, {{Version}}, @Version, ((Version)), (Version), {Version}, #Version, and more. Nothing seems to translate into the value of the Pipeline parameter "Version", when the Pipeline is triggered. How do I do this?

On a related note, is there a way to use the Application name or Pipeline name in Pipeline Stages?

Answer (score 1):

Parameters (and templated pipelines in general) are accessed via [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

If your pipeline has a `Version` parameter and your Jenkins stage has a `Version` parameter, then in the Jenkins stage configuration you explicitly have to map the pipeline's `Version` to the Jenkins stage's `Version` using a value `${parameters.Version}`.

Any pipeline parameter is accessible via the `${parameters.XXX}` syntax.

Have a look at the [pipeline expressions guide](https://spinnaker.io/docs/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/) for more examples.